# Bash-script to toggle espeak by keyboard shortcut

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, case-statement

To read a selected text in GUI out loud I use the command `xsel | espeak-ng -v mb-us3 -p3 -s135`.
To stop it I use `killall -s STOP espeak-ng`.
To start it again `killall -s CONT espeak-ng`.

All 3 commands work, but the noob I am won't let me archive correct results. The problem is in the if- and case-statement I think. I assigned them to a keyboard shortcut.

I want to manage this shellscript to toggle between read aloud and stopping the process of reading aloud if espeak-ng is already running. If it's not already running the bash should start it.

```
0 #!/bin/bash
1 # Name: espeak-en.sh
2 # Author: Karsten Zarth
3 # Created: 2020-08-23
4 # Description: Textselection in GUI is read aloud with english
5 #              male voice with espeak-ng and mbrula
6 #              if already reading: stop
7 #              if stopped: continue
8 # Modified: 2020-08-23
9
10 status=`ps -ef| grep espeak-ng| grep -v grep| awk '{print $5}"`
11
12 if [[ $(pgrep -x espeak-ng) ]]
13         then
14                 case $status in
15                         Tl) killall -s CONT espeak-ng;;
16                         Sl) killall -s STOP espeak-ng;;
17                 esac
18         else
19                 xsel | espeak-ng -v mb-us3 -p3 -s135
20 fi
```

I don't even know how to test the output of: `if [[ $(pgrep -x espeak-ng) ]]`

Can somebody help me to figure out what's wrong and give me some hints? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're on a modern Linux distro, it probably uses systemd. If so, systemd supports per-user services. If you set up espeak as a service, you can use `systemctl is-active espeak` to ask its current status, `systemctl kill --signal=STOP espeak` to stop it, &c; and you don't need to worry about `pgrep`s matching the wrong process, or about race conditions where another process inherits your PID, etc.

Comment: ...which is to say: Mostly, trying to use `ps` or `pgrep` is a code smell. BTW, if you're going to set up a systemd espeak service you could make it socket-activated, so any time data is sent to a socket systemd automatically spins up a copy of espeak, and keeps it around until it's idle for an amount of time you configure, then shuts it down again.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy for your reply, ``system is-active espeak-ng`` doesn't work ``$ systemctl is-active espeak-ng``    
``inactive`` while my long - a bit code smelly, I have to admit - command does. ``$ ps ax| grep espeak-ng| grep -v grep| awk '{print $3}'`` 
``Sl``

Comment: As I said, that works only if you actually make an espeak-ng systemd service. That's a fair bit of work, but it's work that'll leave you with a far more robust solution than you have right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after struggling a bit by myself I found out that there is a difference between `ps -ef` and `ps ax` in the order of printing out some values...

Also I have to admit that the end of line 10 looks awful. It has to be `` ...print $5}'` `` . Because of the difference between `ps -ef` and `ps ax` of course it has to be `` ...print $3}'` `` .

By the way. The dependencies are `xsel` and `espeak-ng` and at least one mbrola-voice.

Now it works. Here is the full code:

```
0 #!/bin/bash
1 # Name: espeak-en.sh
2 # Author: Karsten Zarth
3 # Created: 2020-08-23
4 # Description: Textselection in GUI is read aloud with english
5 #              male voice with espeak-ng and mbrula
6 #              if already reading: stop
7 #              if stopped: continue
8 # Modified: 2020-08-24
9
10 status=`ps ax| grep espeak-ng| grep -v grep| awk '{print $3}'`
11
12 if [[ $(pgrep -x espeak-ng) ]]
13         then
14                 case $status in
15                         Tl) killall -s CONT espeak-ng;;
16                         Sl) killall -s STOP espeak-ng;;
17                 esac
18         else
19                 xsel | espeak-ng -v mb-us3 -p3 -s135
20 fi
```